# Weird behaviour with left bitwise shift in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

While testing out this code

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 32; i++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + ((byte.MaxValue + 1) << i));
 }
```

I get these outputs

```
0 - 256
1 - 512
2 - 1024
3 - 2048
4 - 4096
5 - 8192
6 - 16384
7 - 32768
8 - 65536
9 - 131072
10 - 262144
11 - 524288
12 - 1048576
13 - 2097152
14 - 4194304
15 - 8388608
16 - 16777216
17 - 33554432
18 - 67108864
19 - 134217728
20 - 268435456
21 - 536870912
22 - 1073741824
23 - -2147483648
24 - 0
25 - 0
26 - 0
27 - 0
28 - 0
29 - 0
30 - 0
31 - 0
32 - 256
```

Notice that from 21 to 31, it gives 0's which is the expected behaviour, but on 32, I get back the number 256.

I'm expecting a 0 on 32, but as you can see I got a 256 instead. Can someone please give me some insights on what the dot NET runtime is doing when it sees a left shift 32.

Comment: Isn't this awesome? Left-shifting by 32 is NOT the same thing as 32 left shifts by 1!  Though weird, this is a small improvement over the same operator in C and C++, which defines no particular behaviour for too much left shifting. At least C# behaviour is defined, though somewhat bizarre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually in the C# language spec:

> For the predefined operators, the number of bits to shift is computed as follows:
>
> • When the type of x is int or uint, the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of count. In other
>      words, the shift count is computed from count & 0x1F.

It's also on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx):

> If the first operand is an int or uint (32-bit quantity), the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of the second operand. That is, the actual shift count is 0 to 31 bits.

So shifting an `int` by 32 is exactly the same as shifting it by zero.